# When and how often does the component re-render as users type information in a form?

Tags: react-native, rendering

Let’s say there is a code below where I listen to the event with `onChangeText` inside `MyTextInput` class. I update the state in `onChangeText`, which means the component will re-render.

When and how often does the component re-render as users type information in a form? I’m asking because I don’t believe it’s a good practice to re-render unnecessarily when the users are still in the middle of typing information.

```
export default class MyTextInput extends Component {
    this.state = { text: '' };

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire component doesn't re-render just the text box, read this for more information regarding `setState` and stopping multiple rendering https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60